# Python code to weave rows

Tags: python

I want to write a cleaner version of the code shown below. It's about two different rows consisting of numbers that have to be weaved.

It's for an assignment for a course i'm currently following. This is the assignment:

> ```
> Traveler, if riches are to be achieved, the solution only has to be weaved.    
> 5,4 4,5 8,7
> Weave 6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3
> Weave 7,6
> Weave 9,8
> Weave 5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4
> ```

I have to start with the coordinates on the first row, weave the coordinates of the second row through the first row, then weave the coordinates of the third row through the resulting row etc. Note, if two rows of unequal length have to be woven, the two rows are woven as far as possible. After the elements of the shortest row have been exhausted, the row is completed by adding the remaining elements of the longest row.

The input is this:

```
5,4 4,5 8,7=6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3=7,6=9,8=5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4
```

The output has to be like this:

```
6,4
6,5
10,8
8,8
8,6
7,5
7,3
7,4
5,5
4,2
9,7
10,6
5,3
```

My code is in three files.

### Coordinaat.py

```
class Coordinaat:
    def __init__(self, x_coordinaat, y_coordinaat):
        self.x_coordinaat = x_coordinaat
        self.y_coordinaat = y_coordinaat

    def bereken_nieuw_coordinaat(self):
        self.x_coordinaat += 1
        self.y_coordinaat += 0 
        return self.x_coordinaat, self.y_coordinaat
```

### CoordinaatRij.py

```
class CoordinaatRij:
    def __init__(self, rij):
        self.rij = rij

    def voeg_toe(self,coordinaat):
        self.rij += [coordinaat]

    def breid_uit(self, rij):
        for coordinaat1 in rij:
            self.rij += [coordinaat1]

    def weave(self, weef_rij):
        resultaat = CoordinaatRij([])

        for i in range(len(self.rij)):
            if i < len(self.rij):
                resultaat.voeg_toe(self.rij[i])
            if i < len(weef_rij.rij):
                resultaat.voeg_toe(weef_rij.rij[i])
        if len(weef_rij.rij) > len(self.rij):
            resultaat.breid_uit(weef_rij.rij[len(self.rij):])
        return resultaat
```

### Excerpt of the main code

```
file_input = file.read()
strip_file = file_input.strip()
invoer = strip_file.split("=")

from Coordinaat import Coordinaat
from CoordinaatRij import CoordinaatRij

def nieuwe_rijen(invoer):
    rijen = []
    for i in range(len(invoer)):
        rijen += [CoordinaatRij(invoer[i].split())]
    vorige_rij = rijen[0]

    for rij in rijen[1:]:
        vorige_rij = vorige_rij.weave(rij)
    return vorige_rij

def nieuwe_coordinaten(geweefde_rijen):
    for coordinaat1 in geweefde_rijen.rij:
        huidige_coordinaten = Coordinaat(int(coordinaat1[0]), int(coordinaat1[2]))
        nieuwe_coordinaten = huidige_coordinaten.bereken_nieuw_coordinaat()
        print '%d, %d' %(nieuwe_coordinaten[0], nieuwe_coordinaten[1])

geweefde_rijen = nieuwe_rijen(invoer)
nieuwe_coordinaten(geweefde_rijen)
```

Comment: Thank you, i've editted my code so that it's more clear where the files start!

Comment: Looks good, :) BTW, welcome to Code Review, hope you get a good answer!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I don't understand the correspondence between the input and the output. Could you add an explanation of the input format and how the output must be calculated to your question? (In particular: what to the equality signs mean?)

Comment: Thanks for you feedback! I've editted my question so that now you can see the assignment i'm working on. The "='' sign indicates  the start/end of the different rows that i have to weave.

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/148903/9357) with code in English

Answer (score 5):

English code reads better, since the Python standard library is English.  **If you use Dutch, though, please do so consistently.**  Don't mix `file_input` and `invoer`, or `def weave(self, weef_rij)`.

It's hard to understand what the task to be performed is, and what this code does.  **Docstrings and [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)** would be a good idea.

It is awkward how you do parts of the **parsing all over the place**:

- `strip_file = file_input.strip()` and `strip_file.split('=')` in the main code.  It's especially bad that this snippet is placed before the imports, and before the next line of code (`geweefde_rijen = nieuwe_rijen(invoer)`).
- `invoer[i].split()` within `nieuwe_rijen()`.
- `int(coordinaat1[0]), int(coordinaat1[2])` within `nieuwe_coordinaten()`.

It would be better to get the parsing done all at once, into a list of pairs of integers.  Not only would the code be easier to understand, it would also let the program fail earlier if the input is invalid.

I think you have overdone the OOP here.  There is not much point in defining a `Coordinaat` class, which is basically just a tuple, or `CoordinaatRij`, which is basically just a list.  All you need for this job is **a few functions**.

Specifically, it would be useful to **take advantage of [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)**, which is the core of what you are trying to do.  Then, to transform the result repeatedly for subsequent rows, use the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function.

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest

def coordinaatrijen_parsen(tekenreeks, rij_scheidingsteken='\n'):
    """
    Yield each row of coordinates as a list of (int, int).

    >>> list(coordinaatrijen_parsen('1,2 3,4=  5,6 ', '='))
    [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6)]]
    """
    for rij in tekenreeks.split(rij_scheidingsteken):
        yield [
            tuple(int(c) for c in coord.split(','))
            for coord in rij.split()
        ]

def weven(*rijen):
    """
    Interleave elements from the parameters.

    >>> weven('Geeogn', 'odmre')
    ['G', 'o', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'n']
    >>> weven('Gee', 'odmorgen')
    ['G', 'o', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'n']
    >>> weven('Gd', 'o', 'eemorgen')
    ['G', 'o', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'r', 'g', 'e', 'n']
    """
    return filter(None, chain(*izip_longest(*rijen)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(...) as f:
        rijen = coordinaatrijen_parsen(f.read(), '=')
    resultaat = [(x + 1, y) for x, y in reduce(weven, rijen, [])]
    for coord in resultaat:
        print '%d, %d' % coord
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! Unfortunately, i'm obliged to use classes (as this is part of the course curriculum), so i can't replace the classes with functions. And i'll now look at itertools.izip_longest() , thank you very much!